# How should subscripts be used when evaluating midpoint, trapezoid, and simpsons rule?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, integration

I conceptually understand how these rules work, and I can visually see what I need to calculate, but the subscripts sometimes confuse me.  Some start at $x_{0}$ and others start at $x_{1}$

If I'm looking at evaluating $\int f(x)dx$ using the midpoint rule, well in my mind I see my first interval beginning at $x_{0}$ and the next interval (rectangle) beginning at $x_{1}$ (where the other interval ends).  I then know I have to calculate the midpoint between those two intervals.  So would that mean the initial midpoint is $x_{0}$ or $x_{1}$ or something else?

It makes sense to me when I'm evaluating using specific endpoints like $L$ or $R$, but generally speaking, when considering the Midpoint, Trapezoid, and Simpsons rule, how should one treat the interval subscripts?

Comment: The indices mean nothing on their own. If you want to start the rectangles at a point called $x_0$, then to ahead. If you prefer $x_1$, then use $x_1$. Most importantly, draw a picture, clearly label your points in whatever manner you choose, and then write down your formula in terms of your labeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the midpoint you would have to calculate is the midpoint of $x_0$ and $x_1$, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}(x_0 + x_1)$. This is sometimes denoted $x_{1/2}$; likewise $x_{(2k-1)/2} := \frac{1}{2}(x_k +x_{k+1})$. This notation is very helpful when using Simpson's rule for example.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the intervals and subscripts are confusing.  If I have $n$ intervals I would think my number of subscripts should also be $n$. But if I, for example, have $n=4$ subscripts, I have $4$ subscripts using the midpoint rule, but $5$ using the trapezoid rule.  I guess this is what is confusing me.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You need $n+1$ points to specify $n$ subintervals. At first, it may seem strange that you need one more point than interval, but think about the case $n = 1$. You certainly need two points to determine an interval.